# Unit testing Spring Boot based REST endpoint which returns collection of objects ordered by given direction

Tags: java, spring-boot, unit-testing, spring-restcontroller, spring-boot-test

I am new to spring boot and still learning. Please bear with me if I am asking a question which is not much relevant. I have seen a code something like below and as I understood this code is essentially searching some record based on given sorting order ASC or DESC and return the ordered result set. Do we really need to write a unit test to verify the order of the result set serialized by rest controller or do you think unit testing ordering behaviour is not belong to controller level responsibility ? Your suggestions and thoughts are very much appreciated.

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class OrderController {
    
    private final OrderService orderService;

    @GetMapping("/orders")
    public ResponseEntity<List<Order>> getAllOrders(@RequestParam(required = false) String direction){
        return ResponseEntity.ok(orderService.getAllOrdersSortedByName(direction));
    }

}
```

If we write a unit test like below with mocking service call behaviour, can it be consider as a meaningful test case ?

```
@Test
void findAllOrderDesc() {

    Order o1 = Order.id(1).name("A").build();
    Order o2 = Order.id(2).name("B").build();

        
    when(orderService.getAllOrdersSortedByName(anyString())).thenReturn(List.of(o2,o1));

        mockMvc.perform(get("/orders?direction=DESC"))
                .andExpect(status().isOk())
                .andExpect(jsonPath("$",hashSize(2)))
                .andExpect(jsonPath("$.[0].name",is("B")))
                .andExpect(jsonPath("$.[1].name",is("A")));
                

}
```

Comment: If you used `verify` instead (and not `anyString`) then this could be a useful test that the parameter is passed to the service appropriately. Or you could _not_ mock the response and have this act as an integration test across multiple layers of your application.

Comment: In its current state though, it’s not particularly useful beyond testing that the output comes out as expected json and that the query parameter maps to the method argument as expected.

Comment: Thank you for your reply @BeUndead !
As a general question, is it worth to unit test order of elements return from a service with mocking its behaviour because in this case if we mock service behaviour we literally unit test how spring controller serialize the result with preserving the order of elements return from the service ?

Comment: You should be aware that if you're using Spring Data, you can simply inject a `Sort` object as a controller parameter and pass it through; all of the mapping will happen automatically.

Comment: @Super.Dovra The fact that the controller _doesn’t_ change the order of results is a valid thing to test. It’s not something I would expect to break or change unbenknownst, but it could be worth having. ‍♂️

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, you should test the Controller endpoint as if you don't know that it basically delegates to the Service.

Given that you are mocking the Service response, then you should at least confirm that the JSON has the elements in the expected order. Having said that your test is indeed meaningful (you are not really testing the sorting feature per se but you are testing the JSON serialization assuming that Service already responds with a correct sorting).

Comment: Thank you @João Dias for your answer!